# Calculate the area of a circle using a method

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Why won't this compile?

It seems there is a mistake in `return = n1 * (n2*n2);` but I cannot see it.

I am trying to calculate the area of a circle with a method

```
package week2lab;

public class Week2Lab {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double Pi = 5; 
        double Radius = 3.141;
        double CircleArea = getCircleArea(Pi, Radius);        

        System.out.println("The Area is " + CircleArea);
    }

    static double getCircleArea(double n1, double n2)
    {
        return = n1 * (n2*n2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Voting to close this as off-topic - question is caused by a typo, not likely to help future users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `return  n1 * (n2*n2);` instead of `return = n1 * (n2*n2);`
You should not use `=` sign in `return` statement

Comment: Thanks to both who answered. Much appreciated. Im curious, with so much content on Stackoverflow, how did you guys come across my particular question..Im new to stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1):

You don't use a `=` sign after `return`. Just remove that. And you seem to have swapped the name(s) `Pi` and `Radius` in your post. Additionally, Java already has a [`PI` constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI)<sup>1</sup>. So you could do something like,

```
static double getCircleArea(double radius) {
    return Math.PI * (radius * radius);
}
```

<sup>1<sub>And in that spirit, please use *meaningful* variable names.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thank You, just curious as to how you came across my particular questions when there is so much on Stackoverflow...